# What am I doing wrong with NSDateComponentsFormatter?

Tags: swift, nsdatecomponentsformatter

I recently found out about the new-to-iOS8 class NSDateComponentsFormatter, which lets you format time intervals rather than dates. Cool. I've written code to do this more times than I care to think about. So I decided to try and use it in a playground, but I can't get it to work. Here's my (Swift) code:

```
var componentsFormatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
componentsFormatter.allowedUnits =
  .CalendarUnitHour |
  .CalendarUnitMinute |
  .CalendarUnitSecond

componentsFormatter.unitsStyle = .Positional

let interval: NSTimeInterval = 345.7

let intervalstring = componentsFormatter.stringFromTimeInterval(interval)

println("Interval as String = \(intervalstring)")
```

This displays

> Interval as String = nil

I've tried various things, but no joy. Does anybody have a working example using this new class, or can you spot what I'm missing?

(I speak Objective-C too, so if you have sample code in Objective-C that works as well.)

Comment: Your code worked fine for me. Reports "5:45". What version of Xcode? What target (Mac OS X or iOS)?

Comment: Your code also works for me, on Xcode 6.4, with an iOS playground.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3.1 • Xcode 8.3.2**

```
extension Formatter {
    static let dateComponents: DateComponentsFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.unitsStyle = .full
        formatter.includesApproximationPhrase = true
        formatter.includesTimeRemainingPhrase = true
        formatter.maximumUnitCount = 2
        formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .default
        formatter.allowsFractionalUnits = false
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.year, .month, .weekOfMonth, .day, .hour, .minute, .second]
        return formatter
    }()
}
extension TimeInterval {
    var remainingTime: String {
        return Formatter.dateComponents.string(from: self) ?? ""
    }
}
```

---

```
let interval = 60.0 * 60 * 24 * 7

let intervalstring = interval.remainingTime   //  "About 1 week remaining"
```

---

**Positional Time**

```
extension Formatter {
    static let positional: DateComponentsFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
        formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .default
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
        return formatter
    }()

}
extension TimeInterval {
    var hourMinuteSecond: String {
        return Formatter.positional.string(from: self) ?? ""
    }
}

let time = 345.7

let positional = time.hourMinuteSecond   // "5:45"
```

Comment: When I paste your Swift 1.2 code into a playground, it returns an empty string. A hair better than my nil, but that's only because of your use of the nil coalescing operator.

Comment: @LeoDabus using .weekday in allowed units should crash the code. "To get the correct day of the week, you must create a suitable instance of NSCalendar, create an NSDate object using dateFromComponents: and then use components:fromDate: to retrieve the weekday"

Comment: @user3441734 sorry the correct calendar unit to add there is weekOfMonth. check the last edit

Comment: @LeoDabus please, try to set .maximumUnitCount = 3 and see the result. do you know, why i have 4 units in my resulting string? i am not able to "disable" number of weeks without changing .allowedUnits

Comment: It works for me `(60.0 * 60 * 24 * 7 ) + (60.0 * 60 * 3 ) + 40` returns `About 1 week, 3 hours, 40 seconds remaining`

Comment: @LeoDabus let interval = 1000000000.0; formatter.maximumUnitCount = 3; returns "About 31 years, 8 months, 1 week, 1 hour remaining" to me ... ???

Comment: I get "About 31 years, 8 months, 1 week remaining". Can you post a screen shot of your playground?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142988/discussion-between-user3441734-and-leo-dabus).